# Pass xml definition, via JSON

Tags: php, ajax, xml, json, curl

I'm trying to wrap a full xml content file via json, using ajax and php curl.

My definition in php looks like this :

```
$postData = array(
            'api_key' => $this->access_key,
            'task_store' => array(
                'type' => 'volatile'
                ),
            'tasks' => array(
                'task_name' => 'video.create',
                'preview' => true,
                'definition' => $custom_definition // full path to my xml file
            )
        );
```

This doesn't work. But when I use the plain xml (as a string), it works :

```
$postData = array(
            'api_key' => $this->access_key,
            'task_store' => array(
                'type' => 'volatile'
                ),
            'tasks' => array(
                'task_name' => 'video.create',
                'preview' => true,
                //'profile' => '1080p-24-fps',
                'definition' => "<movie service=\"craftsman-1.0\"><body><stack duration=\"8\"><sequence><overlay duration=\"1\"><image color=\"#000000\" /></overlay><transition type=\"crossfade\" duration=\"1\"></transition><effect type=\"slice\" duration=\"2.5\" ><image filename=\"http://www.censier-publicinex.fr/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/Fotolia_25789474_Subscription_Monthly_XL1.jpg\"/></effect><effect type=\"slice\" duration=\"2.5\" ><image filename=\"http://www.censier-publicinex.fr/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/Fotolia_26368735_Subscription_Monthly_V.jpg\"/></effect><transition type=\"crossfade\" duration=\"1\"></transition><stack duration=\"4\"><stack><effect type=\"none\"><image filename=\"http://www.censier-publicinex.fr/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/Fotolia_23933407_Subscription_Monthly_XL.jpg\"/><filter type=\"gaussianBlur\" diameter=\"0.03\" ></filter></effect><overlay><image color=\"#000000\"><filter type=\"radialGradient\" color0=\"#ffffff\" color1=\"#000000\" point0=\"0.5,0.5\" point1=\"1,1\" ></filter><filter type=\"alpha\" alphaStart=\"0.5\" alphaEnd=\"0.5\" ></filter></image></overlay></stack><overlay duration=\"..\"><text type=\"advanced\" reference=\"AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA&#10;AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA&#10;AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA&#10;\" align=\"center\" fontsize=\"17\" fontcolor=\"#333333\" face=\"arial\">Test</text><animator type=\"grow\" growEnd=\"0.2\"/><animator type=\"custom\"><key time=\"0.0\" pos=\"0,0.2,0\"/></animator></overlay></stack></sequence><overlay left=\"0\" bottom=\"0.07\" height=\"0.09\" width=\"1\"><image color=\"#ffffff\"/><filter type=\"alpha\" alphaStart=\"0.6\" alphaEnd=\"0.6\" /></overlay><text type=\"zone\" left=\"0\" bottom=\"0.07\" height=\"0.09\" fontcolor=\"#000000\" align=\"center,center\">kiki</text><!-- Mentions goes here --></stack>  </body></movie>"
            )
        );
```

Here is the whole method :

```
public function generatePreview($custom_definition) {

    /**
     * Définit le service video.create et la définition xml utilisée
     */
    $postData = array(
        'api_key' => $this->access_key,
        'task_store' => array(
            'type' => 'volatile'
            ),
        'tasks' => array(
            'task_name' => 'video.create',
            'preview' => true,
            'definition' => $custom_definition
        )
    );

    /**
     * Initialise la connexion via cURL
     */
    $ch = curl_init($this->host);
    curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
        CURLOPT_POST => TRUE,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE,
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
            'Authorization: Secret ' . $this->secret,
            'Content-Type: application/json'
        ),
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => json_encode($postData),
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false
    ));

    /**
     * Exécute la requête cURL
     */
    $response = curl_exec($ch);

    /**
     * Vérifie s'il y a des erreurs dans la requête
     */
    if($response === FALSE){
        die(curl_error($ch));
    }
    else {
        echo $response;
    }
}
```

I also tried using `file_get_contents()` function, with no luck : it responds there's an error with the file image.

Has someone already gone through this ?

Comment: Might be helpful to know Which error message you end up with.
Note that there are a number of conversion-options. Which string do you get? I assume that json_encode() converts some syntax-relevant characters like < or >.

Comment: What exactly does `$custom_definition` contain, the path to the file or the contents of it?

Comment: So the error message is a json string response of the service (stupeflix) :
`[{"status": "error", "progress": null, "events": {"started": "2014-06-04T13:32:51.442381+00:00", "completed": "2014-06-04T13:33:13.031493+00:00", "queued": "2014-06-04T13:32:51.388557+00:00"}, "key": "UNLUY5QYBAFKJG2UYPIUMMPENE", "error": "InvalidImageError: Invalid image, file name = http://dev.censier.nm/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/Fotolia_10097174_Subscription_Monthly_XXL.jpg, XML line 11."}]`

Comment: And `$custom_definition` is equal to `file_get_contents($custom_definition)` where `$custom_definition` is the full path to the xml file.

Comment: So the xml is read, but it returns this error :
`[{"status": "error", "progress": null, "events": {"started": "2014-06-04T15:08:31.279265+00:00", "completed": "2014-06-04T15:08:31.842314+00:00", "queued": "2014-06-04T15:08:31.224274+00:00"}, "key": "SUQTCLXBRO6TXKLWQM5EEC3JAE", "error": "Start tag expected, '<' not found, line 1, column 1"}]`
What worries me is situated at the end :
`Start tag expected, '<' not found, line 1, column 1`